# Strange behaviour when trying to install binary within Dockerfile

Tags: linux, docker

I am trying to install the `helm_ls` binary onto a Docker image.

Here is my Dockerfile:

```
ARG OS="linux" \
    ARCH="amd64"

FROM --platform=${ARCH} ubuntu:latest
USER root

RUN apt update -y && apt upgrade -y && \
    apt install curl -y

# I comment out from here downwards
RUN curl -L "https://github.com/mrjosh/helm-ls/releases/download/master/helm_ls_${OS}_${ARCH}" --output /usr/local/bin/helm_ls
RUN chmod +x /usr/local/bin/helm_ls
```

[Here is the repo](https://github.com/mrjosh/helm-ls) for `helm_ls` which shows the installation instructions within the README.

Now if I comment out the last 2 lines, build my image, run it, exec into it and run the `curl` and `chmod` command manually, the binary installs with no issues and I can run it with `helm_ls` on the CLI.

However, if I include the last 2 lines, the image builds successfully, but I cannot execute the `helm_ls` command, I get the error `/usr/local/bin/helm_ls: 1: Not: not found`. I've played around with the base image architectures and install the relevant binary, and I get the same results for anything I try, executing the last 2 commands manually within the running container just works, but for some reason, it doesn't work when the commands are inside the Dockerfile. I'm really stumped and can't see what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to put following line under `FROM` for the two variables to be available in the rest of the Dockerfile

```
FROM ...
ARG OS ARCH
```

Comment: This was it, thank you. Found this thread and it explains that all ARG's are reset after a FROM command: https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/34129

This means that you can use an ARG within the FROM directive, but then you need to recreate it afterwards.